# Grouping anagrams together from a string array

Tags: c#, strings, array

I wrote this code in c#. It is a question from LeetCode, number 49. Given an array of strings, group the anagrams.

The examples it gives are:

> ["eat","tea","tan","ate","nat","bat"]

then return:

> [["bat"],["nat","tan"],["ate","eat","tea"]]

I am wondering what exactly my time complexity is? I believe it is O(2n) which becomes O(n) after dropping the constant. But I am also thinking it might actually be O(2n^2) or O(n^2) because in my first for loop I have `Array.Sort(new string(temp))` which may increase the time complexity. Please let me know.

Overall, how can I improve and speed up my code? Maybe I could get rid of the dictionary? Get rid of `Array.Sort(new string(temp))`? Create one instance of `new string(temp)` and use the variable instead? I am also thinking I should move everything into one for loop. How could this best be accomplished?

```
public IList<IList<string>> GroupAnagrams(string[] strs)
{
    IList<IList<string>> ans = new List<IList<string>>();

    Dictionary<string, List<string>> values = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length; i++){
        char[] temp = strs[i].ToCharArray();
        Array.Sort(new string(temp));
        if (!values.ContainsKey(new string(temp)))
            values.Add(new string(temp), new List<string> { strs[i] });
        else
            values[new string(temp)].Add(strs[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++){
        ans.Add(values.ElementAt(i).Value);
    return ans;
 }
```

Comment: Array.Sort(new string(temp)); -> Impossible to convert from "string" to "System.Array".

Comment: generally, (standard) sorting algorithms have n*log n complexity. So it would be n * (n * log n) + n, which is O(n^2 * log n)

Comment: also it looks like you don't really need temp as a char array, so you could wrap the `new string()` around `strs[i].ToCharArray()`. EDIT: why even use `.ToCharArray()`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my 4 lines long alternative:

```
var anagrams = from word in words
    let pair = new { Original = word, AlphabeticallyOrdered = string.Concat(word.OrderBy(@char => @char)) }
    group pair by pair.AlphabeticallyOrdered into anagram
    select anagram.Select(@group => @group.Original);
```

Here are my line by line explanations:

1. Iterate through the received `words`
2. Create a new string pair where we store the *original word* and the *alphabetically ordered version*
3. Group them based on the *alphabetically ordered version*
4. Retrieve them based on the *original version*

---

If I iterate the result like this:

```
foreach(var anagram in anagrams)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", anagram));
}
```

the output will look like that:

```
eat,tea,ate
tan,nat
bat
```